# How do I pass variables into my class, ID, or data attribute in RiotJS?

Tags: riot.js

I can't seem to figure out how to pass my variable into the class, ID, or data attributes on my custom element.

```
<ub-item class="item cssV2 { opts.status }" id="{ opts.id }" data-link="{ opts.url }">
```

opts.status, opts.id, and opts.url all work if I pass them in an element like `<p>`, but how do I pass the variable into the attributes? The HTML output includes them as strings.

Comment: Is `ub-item` in a custom tag itself? Like a `my-app` tag for instance?

Comment: Yep, it's a custom tag.

Comment: Got a jsbin or codepen we can work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables which will be used in tags should be created using this:

```
<mytag>
 <p class="{ myclass: show }" id="{ myid }" data-link="{ mydata }">Example</p>

 <script>
   this.mydata = 'foo'
   this.myid = 'bar'
   this.show = true
 </script>
</mytag>
```

This will be rendered as:

```
 <mytag>
  <p class="myclass" id="bar" data-link="foo">Example</p>
 </mytag>
```

Comment: I think we need that to say this.myid = 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

My guess, since I' afraid no further informations were provided.

Maybe you just need to assign the opts to self/this to make them available to the view.

```
self = this
self.opts = opts
```

And if the parameters are chaning:

```
self.on('update', function(){
  self.opts = opts
})
```